# How to copy the data to destination range when there is any update in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

Hi everyone,

My goal is to copy the entire row of data from source data to destination range whenever the users select `Transfer` or `Update` in `column E`. Based on my script, it only works perfectly for Employee No 1 (Peter).

For example, when I select transfer in cell `E4`, the entire row of data from cell `A4` to cell `F4` will be copied to destination range (Row 1 in destination range as shown in the screenshot above). When I update certain cell, say cell `C4`, and select `Update` in cell `E4`, the entire row will be copied again to the 2nd row of destination range as shown in the screenshot above.
However, when I select `Transfer` of `Update` in cell `E5` or cell `E6` the data been copied to destination range will still be the data from Peter (Row 3 in destination range as shown in the screenshot above).

I'm not sure how to fix this in my script and really hope to get some helps from you guys.
This is the access to my google sheet for easier reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vfJYOAJT1Lqoj7uYQYftQ39Rl22FR9RWz04d1qYmRkg/edit?usp=sharing

This is my script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();
  var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction
  var aLast = ss.getRange("H"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(direction.UP).getRow()
  var destRange = ss.getRange(aLast+1,8);
  if (e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
    if (e.value == 'Update' || e.value == 'Transfer') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
      
      if(e.range.rowStart = 4) {
        var order1 = ss.getRange ("A4:F4");
        order1.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart = 5){
        var order2 = ss.getRange ("A5:F5");
        order2.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } else if (e.range.rowStart = 6){
        var order3 = ss.getRange ("A6:F6");
        order3.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
      } 
      
      source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

Really appreciate for any helps and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const hr=1;
  if(sh.getName()=='Your sheet name' && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart>hr && (e.value=='Update' || e.value=='Transfer')){
    const dt=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
    let src=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,6).getValues();
    src[0][5]=dt;
    const desrow=getColHeight(8,sh,e.source)+1;
    sh.getRange(desrow,8,1,6).setValues(src);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,6).setValue(dt);
  }
 
}

function getColHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```

Comment: Hi cooper, really appreciate your reply. However, I had tried your script but it doesn't work for me. When I choose `Transfer` or `Update`, it doesn't print anything in my Destintion range. It also unable to print the current timestamp in column `F`. I had posted the link for google sheet in my question, to you mind to have a look on it?

Comment: It works for me I tested it.  You know you can't run these kind of functions from the script editor unless you provide the event object yourself and if you knew what was you probably wouldn't have tried to run it that way in the first place.  So go read about event objects in the guides section of docs near the bottom.  Or simple run it and perform the appropriate edits which is what I do when I test it.